# Maps in Jupyter. Naming locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to give two different names to both locations using count:

location 1
location 2

What am I doing wrong?

```
import folium as fo
map = fo.Map(location=[29.76,-95.36], zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
            
for coordinates in [[29.76,-95.36], [29.75,-95.34]]:
    count = 1
    fg.add_child(fo.Marker(location=coordinates, popup=f"Main Location {count}", icon=fo.Icon(color='green')))
    count = count + 1
        
map.add_child(fg)
```

[locatin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDbnA.png)

Comment: What is `fg` in lines 6 and 9?

Comment: A child object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each loop turn you reset `count` to 1.

Consider :

- initializing count outside of the loop
- using `enumerate` on your list

```python
# Not working
for coordinates in [[29.76,-95.36], [29.75,-95.34]]:
    count = 1
    print(count)
    count = count + 1
​
> 1
> 1

# Working
for index, coordinates in enumerate([[29.76,-95.36], [29.75,-95.34]]):
    print(index + 1)
​
> 1
> 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I did using your method and it worked:

`for index, coordinates in enumerate([[29.76,-95.36], [29.75,-95.34]]):
    fg.add_child(fo.Marker(location=coordinates, popup=f"Main Location {index+1}", icon=fo.Icon(color='green')))`

Comment: Nice. You should mark the question as answered then :)